# Pre Commit hook git error

Tags: python, git

I am trying to execute a pre commit git hook in python to check if files have line lengths less than 80 chars. However i get a no such file/directory error. i am on fedora and have set the #!usr/bin/python.help would be appreciated

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- mode: python -*-

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import sys

def run(command):
    p = Popen(command.split(), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    p.wait()
    return p.returncode, p.stdout.read().strip().split(), p.stderr.read()


def precommit():
  _, files_modified, _= run("git diff-index --name-only HEAD")
  i=1
  for fname in files_modified:

    file = open(fname)
    while i==1:
       line = file.readline()
       if not line:
          break
       elif len(line)>80:
          print("Commit failed: Line greater than 80 characters")
          return 1
    return 0
sys.exit(precommit())
```

Comment: Show us the `git` command you are running and the **precise** error message you receive.

Comment: I run the git commit command and I get the error message no such file or directory.I run the git commit command  error: cannot run .git/hooks/pre-commit: No such file or directory

Comment: Try running the `pre-commit` file directly: `$ ./git/hooks/pre-commit`. Do you get an error message?

Comment: Please copy-paste the precise, complete error message. Don't summarize, don't retype it, just copy-paste it.

Comment: bash: .git/hooks/pre-commit: /usr/bin/python^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory                                                     When i try to run .git/hooks/pre-commit directly i get the above error message

Comment: 1) Is python installed on your PATH? Try "which python" and confirm that it prints "/usr/bin/python". 2) Is it possible that your pre-commit file was saved with DOS line endings instead of Unix line endings? Try "file .git/hooks/pre-commit" and see if it says "CRLF line endings."

Comment: Thank you for pasting the error message.

Comment: .git/hooks/pre-commit: Python script, ASCII text executable, with CRLF line terminators     Ok so i get this message. Python is in my path

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your pre-commit file has extraneous carriage returns in it. This can happen if you edit the file in Windows and copy the file to a Linux computer.

Try these commands:

```
cp .git/hooks/pre-commit /tmp/pre-commit
tr -d '\r' < /tmp/pre-commit > .git/hooks/pre-commit
```

And then rerun your `git` command.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way for '\r' removal is:

```
dos2unix .git/hooks/pre-commit
```