# automatically rejecting a commit based on certain criteria

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I've been looking for this for quite a while myself, but I have nearly no experience with the subject, so I'm just hoping that someone here has come across this before.

Would it be possible to run some kind of a script in SourceTree, which would check the files for some criteria (for example, going through the files checking if "StaticMethodX." is used anywhere and failing the commit attempt if it is?

I'm trying to enforce better coding standards within a team.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either:

- ask your client to use a [`pre-commit` hook](http://codeinthehole.com/writing/tips-for-using-a-git-pre-commit-hook/) (also presented in [this article](http://tech.yipit.com/2011/11/16/183772396/) or illustrated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18885644/6309)), but they can bypass it if they want
- or you can set up a `pre-receive` hook which will deny the push on the server side if your policy isn't followed.
  It would use `git diff-index --cached --name-only`, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2539536/6309) to get the content of each file pushed.

The server-side approach is generally favored, as it is easier to deply, maintain and enforce.

Comment: "The server-side approach is generally favored, as it is easier to deply, maintain and enforce." => but a client side is nice in complement to avoid having to wait until the push to know your commits are broken and unpushable.

Comment: @MatthieuMoy I agree. It is just harder to deploy, enforce and update.

Comment: @VonC: yes, I was not disagreeing ;-). Just complementing your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try npm pre-git which allows you to run commmands on pre-commit and pre-push.
Than open sourcetree using Terminal with following command

```
open /Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/MacOS/SourceTree
```

Now you try to commit and push, sourcetree will run pre-commit and pre-push hooks.